Salesforce get Draft and other row data
Is it possible to get the Draft value and other row data values in a datatable when a user updates a cell?
event.detail.draftValues[0] only returns the value being updated
I want to determine if its ok for the user to edit this cell based on the value of a another cell in the same row. Not sure if it matters, I am using a custom datatable.
Thank you

Only the id and changed values are found in draftValues. You can find the original row data to determine custom logic rules.
handleCellChange(event) {
  // Match the rows in this.data with event.detail.draftValues
  const rows = event.detail.draftValues.map(
    (row) => this.data.find((item) => row.id === item.id)
  ).filter(
    (row) => row.id
  );
  event.detail.draftValues.forEach(
    (row, index) => {
      const beforeUpdate = rows[index];
      // You can now compare row and beforeUpdate
    }
  );
}

